# Enable "Link to a document", but that content type isn't available

Tags: 2010, document-library

I've looked at a few guides on how to enable Link to a Document, such as [this](http://mmman.itgroove.net/2013/02/20/add-link-to-a-document-to-a-document-library/) guide.

The issue is at step 5 in the above guide, I don't have the "Link to a Document" content type. I only have these:

[image]

Where to proceed from here ?

Comment: Are you able to navigate to "<YOURSITE>/_layouts/14/ManageContentType.aspx?ctype=0x01010A"? If its SP2013, navigate to "<YOURSITE>/_layouts/15/ManageContentType.aspx?ctype=0x01010A"?

Comment: No, I'm not. That's a 404 The resource cannot be found.

Comment: Which site template you are using?

Comment: Apparently it's `SGS#0 Group Work Site`